# Enable Data Service on new WSO2 - ESB installation

Tags: service, wso2, esb, migrating

I am trying to migrate an installation of WSO2 - ESB from an old 2003 server to a new 2012 server. The old server had version 2.0.2 while the new server has version 4.8.1. The application is running and I can log in and browse the system. The problem I have is that it appears to be missing components. For example, on the old server there are a list of services including: Proxy, Data, POJO, Spring, Jar ect..on the new server I only have Proxy service. The main service I only need is the Data service but I have no idea how to get that. I am completely new to Java and this application however my boss wants this up and running as the Data service we had on the old server is designed to pull a data feed from a remote SQL server and push it to another server we have. Please help, I have absolutely no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 has a complete middleware stack and it has many components where each of them has it's own specific functionalities so that users can select according to their requirements without overkill the server with lots of features. In abstract [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) do the mediation (proxy), [WSO2 Application Server](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/) do the service hosting and [WSO2 Data Services Server](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/) can be use to pull data out from a remote SQL server which you need to engage with.
Also you can install the features of WSO2 Application Server and WSO2 Data Services Server to WSO2 ESB. But it's bit tricky since we may need to add some configuration files in order to work these feature properly.

Comment: Hi Eranda, thank you for the response. That is how I was thinking the application works but its getting the data services server installed into ESB that as you say is tricky. Is there anything I can read or perhaps you can assist with in order to get the data services server installed? thank you again.